# I created a Carousel Slider in slider.js and first slide of that slider is always blurry

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, carousel

[**picture of blur slide**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDJsv.png)

```
const swiper = new Swiper(".card-swiper", {

effect: "cube",
grabCursor: true,
cubeEffect: {
shadow: false,
slideShadows: false,
},

navigation: {
nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
},


pagination: {
el: ".swiper-pagination",
clickable: true,
},
});
```

**This is the code i used to create that carousel cards but why it is blurry???**

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your question with more details and include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help you debug from there. **What have you done so far to debug this yourself?** What resolution are the images, and what resolution are they being displayed? Is it always _this_ image that's blurry, or always the _first_ image? What happens if you change all images in this slider to be the same image? Are they all blurry?

Comment: Only first card become blurry and when i drag that card it come back in its original form i mean no  blur but when i leave it it become blurry again